# Count duplicates in a google sheet and display value next to count

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Say I have a google form which people input their first and last names in separate questions. In a separate sheet, I would like to have the first name and last name in two columns and then in the next column display the number of responses from the user. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula may work as you want on a separate tab to your Form responses (it assumes the names have been collected in columns B and C so amend as necessary):

`=QUERY(ArrayFormula('Form responses 1'!B2:B&" "&'Form responses 1'!C2:C&{"",""}),"select Col1,count(Col2) where Col1 <> ' ' group by Col1 label Col1 'Name'")`

Comment: Thanks for the help. May I ask what is the purpose of the `{"",""}` included in the array formula?

Comment: Also how could I display the rest of their responses next to the number?